# Cannot connect to local database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble connecting to my localhost database with php. It feels like I have followed every tutorial there is.

current php code:

```
<?php
//ENTER YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION INFO BELOW:
$hostname="localhost";
$database="webutvshop";
$username="dbconnect";
$password="password";

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
     echo "Connection to MySQL server " .$hostname . " successful!
" . PHP_EOL;
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    echo 'Database ' . $database . ' successfully selected!';
}

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

The issue stands, when I acess the file locally on my computer I do not get any answer at all from it. I've tried with many other, yet I do not get any answers from them!

I need help in order to keep working on my schoolproject, thanks.

Comment: What message do you get on screen?

Comment: Try using username "root" and password "" (empty string), this is the default for localhost.

Comment: What do you mean "access the file locally"? You need to access it through a webserver for the PHP code to be interpreted correctly. Do you have a webserver/PHP server installed on your local computer?

Comment: no answer at all = your script is puking with a fatal parse error, most likely, and you've got all debug options turned off. check the error logs, enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting`, or even just try to run the script from the command line, since there's nothing in there that's web-specific

Comment: You should definitely stop using the old way and start using PDO. Just a note

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath Sadly a lot of colleges are still teaching mysql_* functions as the correct way to use MySQL in PHP.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice I am afraid that sometimes is the case. Besides that, there are still tutorials out there which many new developers are also affected by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Stop using `mysql_*`, because they are deprecated officially. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` for this purpose. An example:-**

```
<?php

//ENTER YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION INFO BELOW:
  $hostname="localhost";
  $database="stackquestion";
  $username="root";
  $password=""; // check once with empty password and once with some password that you tried already

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
     echo "Connection to MySQL server " .$hostname . " successful!
" . PHP_EOL;
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,$database);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t select database: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
else {
    echo 'Database ' . $database . ' successfully selected!';
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/7cbr5j

Comment: Even if i try using this code ^ i still do not get any respone whatsoever,

Comment: nada - nothing... Just blank

Comment: working for me perfectly. i change database variables code to show you how to give data and also added output link. check once.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also verify you can connect to the database from a command line:

```
mysql -u dbconnect -ppassword -h localhost webutvshop
```